# What are the other potential downsides, if any, of making `<$>` and `<*>` (but not `pure`) implicit?

Tags: type-inference, syntactic-sugar, applicative-functors

Here, [`<$>`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--36--62-) is the infix functor map operation with type `Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` for any functor type, and [`<*>`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--42--62-) is the sequential application operator on applicative functors `Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`.  The function [`pure`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:pure), of type `Applicative f => a -> f a` is the function for bringing values into an applicative functor, similar to `return` for monads.

A few toy functions to illustrate the question with:

```hs
f x = x + 1
g x y = x + y + 1
h z = z ++ z
```

In a language like Haskell, if we write `f [4, 5, 6]`, we understandably get a type error because the type of `f` is `Num a => a -> a`, and `Num a => [a]` is not a `Num a`.  However, it seems that it would be possible for the compiler/interpreter to notice that `Num a => [a]` is an applicative functorful of `Num a`s and implicitly rewrite the expression to `f <$> [4, 5, 6]`, which does typecheck, and gives `[5, 6, 7]`.

As more complicated example, if write `f [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8], [9]]`, the compiler/interpreter could notice that `Num a => [[a]]` is an applicative functorful of applicative functorfuls of `Num a`s and inject two `<$>`s to rewrite the expression to `(f <$>) <$> [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8], [9]]`, an expression evaluating to `[[5, 6, 7], [8, 9], [10]]`.

You could continue this argument to arbitrarily many functors, and unlike the situation described at the start of [my answer here](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/2541/1777), there's no exponential blowup getting the types to agree since the procedure is to always just unwrap the outermost applicative functor on the argument type until we first find agreement or fail.

(As an aside, the process would have to stop at the first agreement because, taking [David Young](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/users/172/)'s example of `reverse [[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30]]` the programmer always has the option to move the function application inward by writing `<$>` themselves, as in `reverse <$> [[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30]]`, but there would be no easy way to go back out a level.)

Similarly, if the compiler/interpreter finds a non-function applied as if a function, it could look for common applicative functors on the outside of both "function" type and the "argument" type and then inject `<*>`s as needed.  For example, `g [4, 5, 6] [7, 8, 9]` would first become `g <$> [4, 5, 6] [7, 8, 9]` by the rule above and then `g <$> [4, 5, 6] <*> [7, 8, 9]` once it turns out that `Num a => [a -> a]` and `Num a => [a]` describe functions and compatible arguments inside the same functor.  Again, the same trick works on nested functors, though the syntax starts to get fiddly: `g [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8], [9]] [[0, 1], [2]]` implicitly becomes `(<*>) <$> (g <$>) <$> [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8], [9]] <*> [[0, 1], [2]]`.

On the other hand, here I am deliberately excluding implicit lifting of arguments, which sounds much more dangerous—applying a function to a functorful of values seems like a common intent, whereas applying a functorful of computation to a single value is probably much rarer and better written out explicitly.  In particular, an expression like `h 7` would still be a type error under this proposal, not rewritten to `h (pure 7)`.

I am also not suggesting that explicit `<$>`s and `<*>`s or their equivalents should be dropped from the language—there are other situations where a programmer may want to use them, and, anyway, a developer should always have the option to be explicit if that makes the code clearer.

**What are the downsides of implicitly injecting `<$>` and `<*>` (but not `pure`) as described above?**

I will enumerate a few obvious ones below, but I am mainly interested in less obvious consequences.

- **Obvious Consequence A:** The code is less explicit about the computation being performed.  The programmer has to pay especial attention to mismatched types in calls and be aware of the rewrites that are implied.
- **Obvious Consequence B:** The implicit rewrite rules are sensitive to the order of currying.  An expression like `g 4 [7, 8, 9]` would be accepted as meaning `g 4 <$> [7, 8, 9]` because the `<$>` isn't necessary until the end, whereas the symmetric-appearing `g [4, 5, 6] 7` would be rejected because the type-checking rewrite `g <$> [4, 5, 6] <*> (pure 7)` needs a `pure` in order to take the `7` last.  More dramatically, despite `g [4, 5, 6] 7` being rejected, `(flip g) 7 [4, 5, 6]` would be just fine.
- **Obvious Consequence C:** Type inference becomes much more complicated (impossible?), as does reporting type errors in a human-friendly way.

Comment: “Type inference becomes more complicated” sounds like a severe understatement to me. I don’t know how you propose to typecheck a program that works this way. After all, your translation appears to assume that all the types are already known, but this isn’t the case.

Comment: What would `reverse [[1,2,3],[10,20,30]]` evaluate to?

Comment: To me, the most obvious consequence would be that code with a mistake could do the wrong thing instead of giving a type error.

Comment: @DavidYoung Clarified in an edit, though your point might still make a good answer because that seems like a likely footgun.

Comment: @kaya3-supportthestrike Yes, I was trying to capture that in my "Obvious Consequence A".

Comment: Here are some syntax-based approaches that can help simplify the use of applicatives and monads: [Idris's bang notation](https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/interfaces.html#notation) and [idiom brackets](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.3/language/syntactic-sugar.html#idiom-brackets)

Comment: @DavidYoung Nice.  Thanks!  I didn't know about those.

Answer (score 19):

**I would like to argue that your proposal is incompatible with Haskell-style ad-hoc polymorphism and global type inference.** Doing this with the generality you describe would completely break typechecking.

### An example in ordinary Haskell

Consider the simple expression `maybeToList (pure ())`. How do we typecheck this? Let’s begin by considering the known types involved:

```hs
maybeToList :: forall a. Maybe a -> [a]
pure :: forall f a. Applicative f => a -> f a
```

Both of these functions are polymorphic. To typecheck this expression, we must somehow infer which types to instantiate these polymorphic types at. Conventionally, this is done by generating some fresh solver variables—which I will denote `t1`, `t2`, etc.—and then using them to emit a set of constraints:

```hs
t1 ~ [t2]
Maybe t2 ~ t3 t4
t4 ~ ()
Applicative t3
```

Here, `Applicative t3` is an ordinary typeclass constraint, while each constraint formed with `~` is an equality constraint that says the types must unify. `t1` represents the type of the overall expression, so it’s what we’re solving for.

The first and third constraints are easy to solve: we can just take `t1` := `[t2]` and `t4` := `()`. This simplifies our bag of constraints to this:

```hs
Maybe t2 ~ t3 ()
Applicative t3
```

To solve the remaining equality constraint, we utilize the knowledge that type constructors are unique and injective. This means that
$$
∀f\,g\,a\,b.\: (f\ a = g\ b) ⇔ (f = g) ∧ (a = b).
$$
Therefore, we can take `t3` := `Maybe` and `t2` := `()`. This leaves us with simply

```
Applicative Maybe
```

left to solve, which we can satisfy using a top-level instance declaration. All constraints are solved, which means the expression is well-typed. To determine what its type is, we recall that we used `t1` to represent the type of the whole expression, and `t1` = `[t2]` = `[()]`, the expression’s type is `[()]`.

### Attempting this example under your system

If we try to adapt our above reasoning to consider your system, we run into a problem. The issue is that, fundamentally, we cannot emit all these equality constraints! Your proposed system says that the type of a function and the type of its argument do *not* have to match, so our constraints must be more sophisticated.

To understand the implications of your proposal, it is helpful to pin down the actual typing rule it necessitates. My understanding of your proposal is as a modification to the typing rule for function application. Let’s consider the standard rule for function application first:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
Γ ⊢ e_1 : \tau_1 → \tau_2 \\
Γ ⊢ e_2 : \tau_1 \\
\hline
Γ ⊢ e_1\ e_2 : \tau_2
\end{array}
$$
If we just consider automatic introduction of `fmap`, ignoring automatic introduction of `<*>` for now, your proposal modifies the typing rule to the following:

$$
\begin{array}{l}
Γ ⊢ e_1 : \tau_1 → \tau_2 \\
Γ ⊢ e_2 : \tau_3\ (\tau_4\ (\ldots\ (\tau_n\ \tau_1)\ldots))\\
Γ ⊢ \mathsf{Functor}\ \tau_3\\
\vdots \\
Γ ⊢ \mathsf{Functor}\ \tau_n\\
\hline
Γ ⊢ e_1\ e_2 : \tau_3\ (\tau_4\ (\ldots\ (\tau_n\ \tau_2)\ldots))
\end{array}
$$

This rule is dramatically more complicated. The sequence of type constructors $\tau_3$ through $\tau_n$ can vary arbitrarily in length, and it may even be empty. To think about how we might encode this in a Haskell-like type system, we can consider an encoding into modern GHC Haskell that uses a type family to represent the nested sequence of type constructor applications:

```hs
type family Apps :: [Type -> Type] -> Type -> Type where
  Apps '[]       a = a
  Apps (f ': fs) a = f (Apps fs a)

type family All :: (k -> Constraint) -> [k] -> Constraint where
  All _ '[]       = ()
  All c (a ': as) = (c a, All c as)
```

This type family allows us to encode $\tau_3\ (\tau_4\ (\ldots\ (\tau_n\ \tau_1)\ldots))$ as `Apps '[τ₃, τ₄, ..., τₙ] τ₁`, and it allows us to encode the need for each of those types to belong to `Functor` as `All Functor '[τ₃, τ₄, ..., τₙ]`. This is helpful, since it allows us to adapt the equality constraints we generated above to handle your proposed system:

```hs
t1 ~ Apps t5 [t2]
Apps t5 (Maybe t2) ~ t3 t4
t4 ~ ()
Applicative t3
All Functor t5
```

Here, `t5 :: [Type -> Type]`, and it represents the as-yet-unknown list of functorial type constructors that `maybeToList` might need to be automatically lifted over. Note that I am ignoring the additional use of `Apps` that would technically also have to be introduced by the use of `pure`, but that would make this example even more complicated, and your rules suggest that it could be immediately eliminated, so I am omitting it for the sake of simplicity.

Let us consider how we might approach solving this bag of constraints. As before, we can start by immediately solving `t1` and `t4` by taking `t1` := `Apps t5 [t2]` and `t4` := `()`. This leaves us with the following constraints:

```hs
Apps t5 (Maybe t2) ~ t3 ()
Applicative t3
All Functor t5
```

How do we proceed? It’s worth noting that, under GHC’s current typechecking rules for type families, we actually *can’t*. The root problem is that `Apps` is not injective: `Apps '[] (F A)` and `Apps '[F] A` both reduce to `F A`. This makes it very challenging to extract information from this constraint.

Of course, since we’re planning to wire this functionality into the type system, we are not limited to doing whatever GHC’s type family solver happens to do. One way we could make this constraint solvable would be to perform what is known in the literature as [*improvement*](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/224164.224198). Improvement is a process by which the constraint solver can identify unifications that *must* hold in order for a given constraint to be able to be solved, and with luck, those unifications may turn an unsolvable constraint into a solvable one.

In this particular case, we can convince ourselves that the only valid solution for this constraint is if `t5` = `'[]`. We can make this argument by considering that `t3 ()` is always going to be precisely one type constructor applied to a concrete type, and `Apps t5 (Maybe t2)` requires *at least one* type constructor due to the use of `Maybe`. Therefore, if `t5` were ever a non-empty list, the types could not possibly unify, and we can take the improvement `t5` := `'[]`. This allows both `Apps` and `All` to reduce, and we’re left with the constraints from before:

```hs
Maybe t2 ~ t3 ()
Applicative t3
```

These can solve the same way they did before, and we can accept this expression.

### Improvement is sometimes impossible

The complexity involved in the above example is already pretty bad. However, it gets worse: the improvement rule we used does not apply in general, and when it doesn’t, it’s not even clear how to proceed.

Consider the slightly different expression `maybeToList (pure mempty)`. Under ordinary Haskell, this modified expression has the perfectly natural type `Monoid a => [a]`, but under your proposed system, its type is much less clear. It leaves us with the following bag of constraints:

```hs
t1 ~ Apps t5 [t2]
Apps t5 (Maybe t2) ~ t3 t4
t4 ~ t6
Applicative t3
Monoid t6
All Functor t5
```

After taking `t4 := t6`, we’re left with the highly unhelpful constraint `Apps t5 (Maybe t2) ~ t3 t6`, and unfortunately, this constraint is not improvable, as there are infinitely many potential solutions:

- We could take `t5` := `'[]` as before, in which case `t3` = `Maybe` and `t4` = `t2`.
- We could also take `t5` := `'[t7]`, in which case `t3` = `t7` and `t4` = `Maybe t2`.
- In fact, since `t4` could contain any number of applications of some type constructor, `t5` could be of any length at all.

It may seem as though this means we’ve lost [principal types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_type) in our system, but this is not necessarily true. This expression *does* have a principal type, it is just quite the mouthful:

```hs
forall f fs a. (Applicative f, All Functor fs, Monoid (Apps fs a)) => Apps (f ': fs) [a]
```

However, not only is this type somewhat terrifying, it’s also incredibly *ambiguous* in the sense that Haskell uses the term: since `Apps` is not injective, knowing the expected result type at the site that this expression is used may not necessarily be enough to determine `f`, `fs`, and `a`. Moreover, even though this principal type exists, it’s not clear to me that an algorithm exists to reliably infer this type given only the original expression. Perhaps there is some way to do it, but I don’t know what it is.

### What if we abandon global type inference?

Suppose we give up on global type inference. Certainly, if we abandon type inference altogether and demand that the user write all type annotations explicitly, we can implement your scheme, but this means explicitly instantiating *every* polymorphic value, which I think would be considered a non-starter even for languages with exceptionally austere type inference schemes.

A compromise would be to use some form of [local type inference](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/papers/lti-toplas.pdf), which sounds potentially promising. However, it’s worth pointing out that a local type inference scheme would require a significant number of additional type annotations for polymorphic code, and abstractions like applicative functors generally necessitate lots of polymorphic code, so the cure may very well end up being worse than the disease. Nevertheless, you certainly *could* come up with some ad-hoc scheme that would support relatively simple type inference. However, you’re still quite limited in what you can achieve.

The way your proposal works makes a distinction between lifting a *function* and lifting an *argument*. This means that the argument’s type must be determined largely independently from the function’s type! This is a major problem since functions like `pure` are polymorphic in their *return* types, and the `maybeToList (pure ())` example illustrates how this is likely to cause trouble. In such an expression, the type of the argument is determined from its context, but this simply cannot be done in general if every function can be lifted.

You would therefore need to either explicitly annotate this expression and all expressions like it, or you’d need to develop some sort of ad-hoc bidirectional type system that allows propagating expected type information in a sufficiently limited way. Could you design such a thing? Maybe! But it’s not immediately clear to me that it would be usable, so I’m not convinced that local type inference is an easy way out.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing something, and forgive me that this concern is hard to format in a comment, but doesn't this definition of `<:` treat `<$>` as having type `(Functor f, Functor g) => (a -> b) -> f a -> g b` instead of `Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, and that's the real source of the problem in your example?  [contd.]

Comment: If we insist that the functors wrapped around a function's result agree with those unwrapped from its argument, then instead we get the system `t1 ~ t5… [t2] ∧ t5… Maybe t2 ~ t6… t3 t4 ∧ t6… t4 ~ () ∧ Applicative t3` where `t5…` and `t6…` both represent (possibly empty) sequences of functors, and that system does have a unique solution `t1 = [()] ∧ t2 = () ∧ t3 = Maybe ∧ t4 = () ∧ t5… = {no functors} ∧ t6… = {no functors}`.  (It might still be the case that type inference breaks on some other example, though.)

Comment: @Wheelwright You’re right that I made a small mistake in failing to adequately account for the consistency in the result. I do think you’re right that you could extend the “subsumption” relation to be indexed by a list of type constructors of kind `Type -> Type`, but this significantly complicates the type system, as now you are dealing with type-level lists. If you want to retain principal types, those lists must somehow be manifested in the source language, and standard Haskell certainly does not support that.

Comment: @Wheelwright Moreover, we can easily make the example definitively fail to typecheck by wrapping the expression in `show`, since `show` requires the type of its argument to be unambiguous. Perhaps you could introduce some special defaulting scheme for these type-level lists, much as `Num` is defaulted to `Integer`, but this is already growing quite complex.

Comment: Regarding the latest edit, I don't think we can soundly say a priori that `t3 t4 <: Maybe t2` because the result of `pure` might be wrapped in functors (the `t6…` in my `t5… Maybe t2 ~ t6… t3 t4`).  We would have to first unify `t4` with `()` to know that there are none there.

Comment: Regarding introducing type-level lists, that would be a mess, but, AFAICT, it's not actually necessary here.  Under the proposal, a placeholder like `t5…` can only appear on the very outside of an expression being unified.  So, whenever we have a constraint where only one side is prefixed by such a placeholder, we know how many type constructors it represents, and we can replace it everywhere with an appropriate-length sequence of fresh variables.  [cont'd.]

Comment: If somehow a constraint with placeholders on both sides survives these replacements, then the types are surely underspecified, and we report an error.  Otherwise, we've boiled the problem down to a system of constraints that an ordinary type checker can handle.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand what you're getting at with `show`.  (It could be that I'm being dense.)  Could you explain in your answer?  (I hope that I don't sound ungrateful with these comments; your input has been very helpful!)

Comment: @Wheelwright I finally took the time today to go through this more thoroughly. I think you were largely correct—when I took the time to work out the informal reasoning I had in my head, I realized it was actually wrong! Initially I thought perhaps my answer was unsalvageable, but after working through things a bit farther, I think the damage was not nearly as bad as I’d initially feared. I’ve largely rewritten the middle section; let me know if it makes more sense to you.

Answer (score -3):

My experience in functional programming is actually limited. Tell me if I misunderstand anything. What you have described is sometimes called [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization) (unhelpful link), or [array programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming) (unhelpful term, but Wikipedia calls it this). I'm assuming you are asking about vectorization in general, not limited to functional programming language.

I don't think it has big downsides, as it is already done in many languages, if we don't restrict it to functional programming languages. But it may need to be designed carefully, to avoid pitfalls.

### Mixing of dimensions

if `x` is `[a, b, c]` and `y` is `[d, e, f]`, `x + y` actually has two different intuitive meaning. One is to add corresponding elements, the other is to add all pairs as in a Cartesian product. The later also has an implementation detail that whether the result is one dimension or two dimensions.

If you choose corresponding elements, where the term vectorization is most appropriate, people may expect if `a + y` and `b + y` are valid, `[a, b] + y` is automatically always valid and always means the previous two combined into an array. But it is not true. If `y` is actually `[d, e, f]`, `[a, b] + [d, e, f]` would be an vectorized operation on lists with unequal sizes, which may not make much sense, or at least doesn't give the expected result.

If you choose all pairs, as defined in the question, I was once in that situation, before knowing APL I think, in a procedural programming language, not even objective oriented. In that language, parameters are always passed by references, so every parameter is both an input and an output of the function. Problem arises when you call multiple functions with the same parameters in a sequence:

```
var1 = input
var2 = var3 = 0
func1(var1, var2, var3)
func2(var1, var2, var3)
func3(var1, var2, var3)
```

Think about expanding another function calling the three functions to its internal content. The later functions are supposed to use the previous function's one set of consistent output as the input, but it actually gets the Cartesian product of all parameters across different sets of data. This is especially a problem if you don't want to restrict the parameter types in most functions, where wrapping them into a function would still be equivalent to them, and there won't be an easy way to get the desired semantic.

It's much more hidden in a functional programming language, where multiple return values are not in the basic syntax. You may get some problems once you wanted to split multiple return values. And you may have different problems if you use different ways to split them and use them.

But a simple possibility would be someone defines a function without specifying the parameter must be non-array, and use its parameter two times in the function, and someone calls it on an array. These two functions would be very different if the type of x is not specified:

```
f x = x + x
g x = 2 * x
```

### Strings

In many languages, strings work like arrays of characters. But they are often logically like simple values that should not be vectorized into while you are vectorizing a list of them. The inherited properties of arrays would become a trouble. A common use case is to do vectorized concatenation. Someone may expect `["a", "b"] ++ ["c", "d"]` to work, but it obviously doesn't because the operator `++` already had a meaning in this case, which is array concatenation. You may make strings and character arrays different, and define different operators for them. But the programmers need to remember more things, and there might be another case that also use arrays as simple values.

If the language supports operator overloading, programmers should also be careful not to overload the array operations, so that they won't make the operator unable to be vectorized. If you provide some nice operators such as union and intersection, that means the overloadable options are fewer. Worse if you ever add predefined overloading to already overloadable operators.

### The solution in APL

In APL, arrays could be "enclosed" to make it like a simple value, called a scalar value. Vectorized operations are on corresponding scalar elements, and could be vectorized recursively for the basic operations that are inherently vectorized. Non-vectorized functions could be non-recusively vectorized to the level of scalar values using an operator, just like using your implicit modifications explicitly. But arrays could have multiple dimensions above the scalars, without enclosing, different from nested enclosed arrays. So you could still take advantage of vectorization to work with strings, for not needing to specify the number of levels, and not needing to write that operator many times, by making strings enclosed scalars in a bigger array of any number of dimensions. You could also specify the dimension while using many functions, and there is an operator for outer product, to help dealing with dimension problems.

There are built-in functions (used like operators in other languages, but "operators" in APL refer to high order functions) to enclose a dimension, and "disclose" to extract from scalar values to make a new dimension, to convert between the two formats. You may think multi-dimensional arrays doesn't conflict with the concept of functors, but it requires slightly more thinking to allow moving a dimension in and out, as a basic feature to support this semantic better.

Vectorization is basically a possible property of a function. User defined functions are not by default vectorized, mostly because parameter types are not usually specified, so the interpreter wouldn't know if your function already makes sense directly on arrays. But many user defined functions could appear as vectorized, because you call vectorized functions for simple calculations in its implementation.

I repeat that my answer only says it may need to be designed carefully. So APL might not be removing all the above listed situations. In some cases it instead defined more things to work with the listed situations, to supplement the implicit injection.

Comment: It's not clear in this how it applies to any functor other than list (or ZipList); what is the equivalent translation to e.g. the Maybe or function Functors, or even something like Product?

Comment: I'm a little torn on how to vote on this.  Like mentioned above, the question is about all applicative functors; lists were just an example.  The discussion on mixing of dimensions is a good answer, but to a different question, since here those decisions were already all made by how the type was defined as an instance of `Applicative`.  The other parts get at possible ambiguity about what "level" a reader will think the function applies at, like in the `reverse [[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30]]` example, and that's an on-topic concern, so maybe refocus the answer on that idea?

Comment: I don’t think this answers the question.

Comment: @Wheelwright Is the difference between `f x = x + x` and `f x = 2 * x` considered a problem in you design? If it is, maybe I could refocus.

Comment: Both of those functions would be completely interchangeable as far as this question goes, as would any other function with type `(Num a) => a -> a`.

Comment: On CodeReview, JimmyHu posted several iterations of a generic recursive transform function for C++ (see their [list of questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/231235/jimmyhu?tab=questions)). We encountered the issues you mentioned (mixing of dimensions, the issue with strings being containers as well). You also might want to let recursion stop at a given level, or when reaching a certain container type. Then there things like variants that could also be handled in two ways (apply the function to the whole variant or to the value contained within?).

Comment: What you call "vectorized operations" and APL calls "scalar functions" don't really work how you explain they do, scalar functions *do* go through boxes, but after they have been interpreted as scalars. The section could probably be written more clearly, it seems to imply that `1 2 3+⊂4 5 6` wouldn't work, or that's what I understand it to mean. Also, in the context of APL, where "function" and "operator" mean vastly different things, I wouldn't use them interchangeably.

Comment: @MichaelHomer The situation I'm talking about is when the type isn't specified. So there isn't a `Num a` specified, and `a` could already be a list or other functor, and the implicit injection may happen inside the function `f`, instead of outside. If you insist on it, then the catch becomes you have to clearly specify the type everywhere, which doesn't conflict with the first part saying "no big downside, but must be designed carefully to avoid pitfalls".

Comment: RubenVerg was correct, but let me think for a while, because I don't know why I thought the APL model like that...

Comment: @RubenVerg Yes. My fault, and I don't know why I thought like that. Tried to rewrite that part a bit and I hope it could still convey some ideas.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question. It is perhaps an interesting answer to an entirely different question. But it really does not answer this question in any capacity. It is somewhat remarkable to me that it has currently attracted 4 upvotes in spite of this fact.

Comment: @AlexisKing While I still don't think this answer is completely irrelevant, as what OP devises have some semantic problems even if consistent, maybe create some restrictive tags for Haskell-like languages. Type-inference and applicative-functors have many possibilities to be mixed with non-Haskell-like features, in contrast to e.g. how statically typed is definitely not dynamically typed, which I added to one of my question for clarity.